# UITableView async image dynamic height jumping

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, sdwebimage

I'm currently working on a project where I need to display a Facebook like feed with (depending on uploaded or not) a imageview and multiline label. 
I already created a custom UITableViewCell, and the text content is showing correctly and changing the height of the cell with autolayout. But when a image is loaded into the imageview (with dynamic height), the tableview starts to jump, probably because the cell sizes are changing. I'm using SDWebImage to load the images.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

**SOLUTION:**
What we did is pre-load the images. Then build the tableview and cells.

Below my custom cell layout in the interface builder, the small stroke on the bottom is the dynamic image:
[image: Custom cell]

Comment: is there a need to have dynamic image sizes for your list, i would have thought it would better better looking for the images to be locked to a certain size

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift). They have explained everything in detail. Hope this helps

Comment: Are your images of dynamic size? Or Just the multiline text?